# how to compare order of two list when one list is not stable

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have some string objects which I store inside a List,

for example : [US, CN , IN, EN, FR, GR, PL, MX]

and the order of the expected list should be same as above list all the time.

but the catch is, the list i am using to compare sometimes does not have any of the above country codes...

for example the list i am comparing with is [US, CN, EN, GR,PL, MX]

but it should pass and return true because its in the same order as the first list.

if the list is like [CN, US, EN, GR, PL, MX] it should fail because CN came before US.

it does not matter if the list has all the values or not, even if we skip some country code it should pass if the order of the other country code is correct

Please give me an idea about what is the best way to do?

Comment: So ALL the items in the "compare list" should be contained in the original list and both of them should be ordered the same way?

Comment: all the items may not be there in compare list thats my issue :( some time it changes, i cannot guess what would be there until i get the data.

Comment: but the compare list should be in order, for example US should not come after CA or any other country code,  even if couple of code missing, it should still check if the order is same or not. weather US is coming before CA or after :(

Comment: Ok both lists should have the same order, but what i'm also asking is that if the first list is like this: [US, CN , IN, EN, FR, GR, PL, MX] and the second list is like this: [US, CN , IN, EN, PL, MX , ARG] ... should the test pass? (same order but second list has ARG element which first list does not contain)

Comment: there will be nothing more other than the first list comes, only chance is to reduce the country code, wont be having any extra coming other than the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove all items from the list to check against and then compare the two lists:

```
public static boolean check(String checkedAgainst, String items) {
    List<String> checkedAgainstList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(checkedAgainst.split("\\s*,\\s*")));
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(items.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
    checkedAgainstList.retainAll(list);
    return checkedAgainstList.equals(list);
}
```

Test:

```
boolean valid = check("US, CN , IN, EN, FR, GR, PL, MX", "US, CN, EN, GR,PL, MX"); // true
```

Comment: @sarath Just remember to always create a new `ArrayList<> checkedAgainstList` as it gets modified by `retainAll()`.

Answer (score 1):

We can map each element of lists being checked to its corresponding (`indexOf`) index in the "order" (first) list, and then check that each such index is greater than or equal to the one preceding it.

An index list with no element smaller than the one preceding it can be considered correctly ordered.

Lists:

```
List<String> order = Arrays.stream("US, CN , IN, EN, FR, GR, PL, MX".split(","))
        .map(String::trim)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> list1 = Arrays.stream("US, CN, EN, GR,PL, MX".split(","))
        .map(String::trim)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> list2 = Arrays.stream("CN, US, EN, GR, PL, MX".split(","))
        .map(String::trim)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Checking order:

```
//range(1, list1.size()) assumes list1's size is at least 2.
boolean list1Ordered = IntStream.range(1, list1.size())
        .allMatch(i -> order.indexOf(list1.get(i)) 
                >= order.indexOf(list1.get(i - 1))); //returns true
boolean list2Ordered = IntStream.range(1, list2.size())
        .allMatch(i -> order.indexOf(list2.get(i)) 
                >= order.indexOf(list2.get(i - 1))); //returns false
```

Note that the above considers "ordered" when two consecutive elements of `list1` are the same (change to `>` if logic says otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

Here one more solution with TestNg Assert:

```
List<String> baseList = Arrays.asList("US", "CN" , "IN", "EN", "FR", "GR", "PL", "MX");
List<String> newList = Arrays.asList("US", "CN" , "EN", "GR", "PL", "MX");

int index = baseList.indexOf(newList.get(0));
for (int i = 1; i < newList.size(); i++) {
    int nextElementIndex = baseList.indexOf(newList.get(i));
    Assert.assertTrue(nextElementIndex > index, "List order correct");
    index = nextElementIndex;
}
```